# spring not able to find JNDI data source

Tags: spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I am developing a spring web application . A JAR file which I use in my application , is looking for DataSource using JNDI. I configured the  element in my tomcat's server.xml. The configuration is as below ,

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource name="jdbc/abcd" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            maxActive="70"
            maxWait="10000" 
            username="xxxx" password="yyyy" 
            validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:zzzz"
            testOnBorrow="false"
            testOnReturn="false"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="120000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
  />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

The Resource name configured above , "jdbc/abcd"  is the same which the JAR is looking for,
But its not able to find this configured data source . Does anyone know what could be the reason ?

Am getting the below exception ,

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Comment: Can you provide the application context, where you lookup your datasource

Comment: am not getting your question . actually am new to web application development . Can you tell what do you mean by 'application context' ?

Comment: The Spring Framework defines a container area which is called "application context". Thats e.g. a XML file called "application-context.xml" which has Bean definitions within. [This part](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) of the Spring Documentation will give you more details.

Comment: I don't think Spring or Spring configuration is the problem here. He is using an external jar file that seems to have a dependency to a J2EE resource named jdbc/abcd. What he need to do is defining this resource in the J2EE context for his application. I don't think the Spring application context is relevant.

Comment: No, "jdbc/abcd" is shorthand for the JNDI name.  It should be "java:comp/env/jdbc/adbc" for Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a ResourceLink in the web application context that makes the global resource visible to the web application.

```
<ResourceLink 
        name="nameThatIsVisibleToTheWebApplication"
        global="theGlobalName"
        ...
```

Comment: should I put this in  web.xml ?

Comment: @Mariselvam You can put it into the context.xml file which is located in the /conf folder where the server.xml resides,too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do more than just configure Spring.

I'd recommend reading [Tomcat JNDI documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) and [this](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-use-same-jndi-resource-name-on.html).